# How to save text attribute set to a file?

Tags: java, text, attributes, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I am writing a basic text editor and have functionality that allows the user to change the font and apply styles like making it bold etc. I do this using the AttributeSet interface and StyledContext class and the insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) method in a DefaultStyledDocument. However I save and re-open the same file (where the text has been written using BufferedWriter), and all of the styles I applied to the text are no longer there. Is there another way to write the extra style information and read it from a .txt file, if so how? Thanks.

Comment: one word, well initialism, `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

A plain text file will not preserve your style information.
One way of mixing text and styling instruction is using a [markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language), for example HTML. You can use a known markup language such as HTML, [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) (there are many others) or create your own one. For example, you can create a simple markup language based on XML which can suite your needs.
There are some open source Swing rich text editors you may want to take a look at, for example: [JRichTextEditor](https://github.com/hoesterholt/JRichTextEditor).

Another option is saving your document in a binary format which will include the styling instructions.